# Why does rotating a TIFF in Preview increase the file size?

Tags: preview, image-editing

When I use Preview.app to rotate a .TIFF image file 90 degrees, the resulting file is about 10% to 20% larger. All I do is open, rotate, save; there is no exporting or "save as" changes. I've tried this on multiple TIFF files and the behavior is constant.

It's the same file with the same data, so why the size increase?

<sup>(2013 rMBP) -- (OS X 10.11.4)</sup>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So when you make any changes to a file and 'save' it in Preview, the file is re-encoded.  It must be using different settings that the program that originally created it.

It has nothing to do with rotating.  If it did you could try rotating it back and the file size would drop, but that's not the case.

I just tried saving a TIF and I can see that Preview seems to be adding an Alpha channel to the image.  Not sure if that would be the reason for the increase, but it is something that is different.

[image: Alpha channel being added when saving with Preview.]

Comment: I think you are right. SE doesn't encourage asking different questions in one question, so I have created a new, related question here: [_What application can rotate a TIFF without re-encoding it?_](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/239492)